# How can i stop this simple php calendar from caching the old dates?

Tags: php, html

I made this simple calender for a few friends to fill in all their dates, It all works fine when you update the dates but then when you go back to the calendar it shows all the old dates selected. You have to manually refresh the page to get the updated dates it's really frustrating.

You can demo it here: http://olli460.com/poker/index.php

If you click "Add/Edit Dates" then click on "oliver" and select a few random dates. When you go back to the calendar it's still showing all the old dates until you press F5.

This is my index.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
$pageWeb = $_REQUEST['page'];
$pageWeb = filter_var($pageWeb, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if(empty($pageWeb)) {
  $pageWeb = "main";
}

$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxx") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>


  <title>Poker Calendar</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="shortcut icon" sizes="192x192" href="if_icon-82_667352.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!--<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">-->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />

    </head>
<body>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/8a36931ffe.js"></script>



    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">Poker Calendar</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li <?php if(empty($pageWeb)) { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>><a href="index.php"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Calendar</a></li>
            <li <?php if(empty($pageWeb) OR $pageWeb == "add-dates") { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>><a href="index.php?page=add-dates"><i class="fa fa-calendar-plus-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add/Edit Dates</a></li>
            <li <?php if(empty($pageWeb) OR $pageWeb == "add-player") { echo "class=\"active\""; } ?>><a href="index.php?page=add-player"><i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add Player</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
 <br /><br /><br /><br />


<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- START ALL CONTENT HERE -->
                <?php
                  if(isSet($pageWeb)){
                  if (!(strpos($pageWeb, "http") === false)){
                   echo "not allowed";
                  }else{
                    include("$pageWeb.php");
                  }

                  } else {
                    include("main.php");
                  }
              ?>
    <!-- END ALL CONTENT HERE -->

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

After they enter the dates i'm using this to redirect back to the main page, is this the issue?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                location.href = "index.php";
            }, 3000);
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Just tried that, same error dates dont actually show until i press F5

Comment: it's an add OR edit facility.. if the dates are not cached, how can they be edited? I don't see why that's an error?

Comment: Theres no errors, It's just displaying the old dates for some reason i dont understand why.

Comment: it showed the edited dates when I edited them?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to fix that script, tell the browser not to cache the page:

```
<?php
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

and why load data from mySQL? maybe use the [Google Client Library](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) ([GitHub](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client)) instead?

Comment: this seems a little overly complex i only want a basic calendar for a couple of friends. I've done a similar script before and that worked fine i cant understand why this one is caching like it is

Comment: @Exoon it it rather overly complex not to use a library - while your question is lacking half of the scripts. guess I know what the issue is, because my browser told me "from disk".